# Using grep for searching in text file with ignore

Tags: regex, grep

I want search in text files in a variable folder a variable string by using "**grep**". I want him to ignore the first 6 character and the last 6 character while he is searching in the file.

Example line in file:

```
xxxxxx TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT xxxxxx
```

somthing like this:

`grep -PInr "[^......]TEXT" /var/local/data/textfiles/`

Comment: what did you try? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: im sorry: i tried this:

`grep -PInr "[^......]TEXT" /var/local/data/textfiles/`

Comment: please do [edit] your post with this information. All those `-P`, `-r` seem superfluous.

Comment: @fedorqui why superfluous?

Comment: `-P` is for extended regular expressions, which are not present here. `-r` is for recursive, while you say _search in a text file_. `-I` is for binary files, which may not be the case.

Comment: And, again, please provide a [mcve] to have a more representative use case. Otherwise, we would assume that `grep "TEXT" file` suffices.

Comment: i have edit the main topic...**text fileS**....
every line has the following construction

`xxxxxx TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT xxxxxx`

Comment: Have you tried `grep '^.......*TEXT.*......$' /var/local/data/textfiles/`?